# Test Circuit for Bipolar Amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt

I have this BJT test circuit to measure its Base-Emitter Voltage and I'm having some difficulties to understand what's the purpose of the lower Op Amp. Is it in a negative feedback?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm having some difficulties to understand what's the purpose of the
> lower Op Amp. Is it in a negative feedback?*

It keeps the base current at a constant value of \$\frac{V_X}{R_B}\$.

Yes, local negative feedback through the transistor base-emitter junction maintains the virtual ground (i.e. \$V_B= \text{0 volts}\$) and keeps the base current constant. The OP-07 will adjust its output voltage to about -0.7 volts to overcome the natural base-emitter forward voltage.

The collector current and base current (sum = emitter current) flow into the lower OP-07's output and the upper OP-07 monitors collector current and fixes the collector voltage at 0 volts (BJT at point of near-saturation).

If the upper OP-07's non-inverting input was (say) raised to a higher DC voltage than 0 volts, the collector would be forced to be at that same voltage. I mention this because that is a more common test for BJTs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful.